# Match multiple strings and print if both string on the same line - awk

Tags: bash, awk

This works fine if I want to find defstring3.

```
defstring1=name
defstring2=surname
defstring3="defstring1 defstring2"
echo "name surname is:" $(awk -v string="$defstring3" '$0~string' namelist) >> result
```

But I want to eliminate defstring3 and use defstring1 and defstring2. So I want the code search entire namelist text file and print out if both defstring1 and defstring2 are on the same line. I kept trying but could not find it. Something like this ...

```
echo "name surname is:" $(awk -v string1 ="$defstring1" string2="defstring2" '$0~string1~string2' namelist) >> result
```

Comment: note that your `defstring3` is not what you think it is.  It doesn't have the values of the variables but instead the variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
echo "name surname is:" $(awk -v string1="defstring1" string2="defstring2" '$0~string1 && $0~string2' namelist) >> result
```

In my test:

```
$ cat foo.txt
foo
bar
foobar
$ awk -v string1="foo" -v string2="bar" '$0~string1 && $0~string2' foo.txt
foobar
```

Comment: Thank you! I do not know why I did not try &&. haha !

Answer (score 2):

currently you're testing a stronger condition "x y". Now you want "x" AND "y".  The syntax is:

```
$ awk -v x="$value1" -v y="$value2" '$0~x && $0~y'
```

if you want the exact replica of the current behavior

```
$ awk -v x="$value1" -v y="$value2" '$0~x" "y'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.